# Floating Point double constants treated as extended

Tags: delphi

In a 664 bit app, If I compare a floating point constant to a value obtained from StrToFloat() for the same "value" I get a different results. For example:

```pascal
procedure foo;
const
  d1 = 0.6694716
  d3: double = 0.6694716
var
  d2: double;
begin
  d2 := StrToFloat('0.6694716');
  if d1 = d2 then
    beep;
  if d1 = d3 then
    beep;
  if d2 = d3 then
    beep;

end;
```

The d1 and d3 have a hex value of $B47339B4 while d2 has a hex value of $B47339B3. While they are "equal" for a comparison. They technically are not the same. From what I can tell, the constants d1 and d2 are wrong. Perhaps the compiler uses the FPU and this is due to rounding?

Short of making all my constants as strings and converting them at run time. Anyone know of  a work around for this?

Comment: This is how floating-point values work. You don't need any workaround.

Comment: @andreas You sure? It is known that StrToFloat is defective. The compiler however does these conversions correctly.

Comment: @Bill Delphi's library code to convert from float to text and from text to float is defective. For this reason I replaced that code with external libraries that do it correctly. I would trust the compiler here, so I think d1 will be correct. The compiler is written in C and I believe its runtime is fine for text to float.

Comment: `StrToFloat()` converts to the extended format if possible. Then it is converted to a double.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Is `StrToFloat` defective? Didn't know that. That's bad.

Comment: In any case, the error `Abs(d2 - d1) = 5.55E-17` isn't huge.

Comment: Interestingly d1 doesn't agree with my code, which I know to be correct, so perhaps that's because of the type of d1

Comment: Of course floating points are always "approximates" but I would have expected constancy.  Technically, I only showed FloatToStr() as it gets the correct answer. The issue is the const value. It does not get the same value as my C++ code nor any line converters (https://gregstoll.com/~gregstoll/floattohex/)

Comment: Try `ShowMessage((Extended(0.6694716) = Double(0.6694716)).ToString(TUseBoolStrs.True));` first on Win32, then on Win64. On Win64, `Extended` is an alias for `Double`.

Comment: I should note that this is a 64 bit app. Not sure what it does for a 32 bit app.

Comment: That StrToFloat doesn't return the same value as dtoa implies that StrToFloat is defective

Comment: That said, StrToFloat does return same as dtoa for 64 bit, so I'm at a loss here

Comment: Assuming the online tool I used is reliable, it seems like the error in `d1` is 5.5530335885123E-17 while the error in `d2` is -5.5491966577392E-17. So `d2` is "better". But recall that a double doesn't have more than 15 significant digits.

Comment: You could file a bug report in Embarcadero's Jira, so that the compiler experts can have a say on this one.

Comment: `struct.pack(">d", 0.6694716).hex()` is `3fe56c4fb47339b3`. StrToFloat returns this in 64 bit but in 32 bit it returns `3fe56c4fb47339b4`.

Comment: David, I found the same. From what I can tell, the c++ looks correct, the StrToFloat looks correct but "const" is not! So it looks like the compiler may be using extended for the conversion from source text and then converting it to double.

Comment: Update topic to better describe the problem and to show a third option that also fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disgusting as it is, I put the const as string values and the convert them to double in the unit initialization.  That way we get double not extended math. This seems to work. I expect it will not work with 32-bit.

```pascal
function HexToDouble(const val: uint64): double; inline;
begin
  result := Pdouble(@val)^;
end;

//use
D1 := HexToDouble($3fe56c4fb47339b3);
```

Comment: Better would be to put the true binary value in as a UInt64 constant `$3fe56c4fb47339b3` and copy that with a `Move`. `procedure foo;
const
  d1_i64: UInt64 = $3fe56c4fb47339b3;
var
  d1: Double;
begin
  d1 := PDouble(@d1_i64)^;
end;
`

Comment: (Or any other of the many variants: `var
  d1: Double; d1_x: UInt64 absolute d1;
  d2: Double;
begin
  d1_x := $3fe56c4fb47339b3;
  d2 := StrToFloat('0.6694716');
  if d1 = d2 then
    Beep;` If you can tolerate a tiny performance hit, you can make a nice inlined helper function `HexToDouble` and write `d1 := HexToDouble($3fe56c4fb47339b3)`.

Comment: Good point. The it does not rely on StrToFloat(). For readability, can put the decimal numbers as comments.

Comment: added final solution (at least for now)

Answer (score 2):

Float literals in Delphi are Extended by default. In 64 bits, that shouldn't make any difference, but in 32 bits it does.  My guess is that the parser still internally represents float literals as a 10 byte float(extended), and then the 64 bits compiler "round it down" to 8 bytes(double) when compiling.

If my hypothesis is right, there might be nothing that can be done to circumvent that.

EDIT

Delphi does the following conversion

- Double(3FE56C4FB47339B3) converts to Extended(3FFEAB627DA399CD9800)
- Double(3FE56C4FB47339B4) converts to Extended(3FFEAB627DA399CDA000)
- 0.6694716 is Extended(3FFEAB627DA399CD9C00)

Comment: You mean that even the 64-bit compiler uses `Extended` for floating-point literals? That seems plausible. If the conversion is done already by the tokenizer, there's not much you can do about it. For instance, `d1 = Double(0.6694716);` won't help you.

Comment: Not so much the compiler than the parser, but yeah... That's what I mean.I don't know much about compiler technology, but I'd expect all compilers to  use the same parser. If the parser is "compiler agnostic", it needs to preserve the  litteral as a 10 bytes value for the 32bits compiler. Considering the impact, if probably should keep both so the 64 bits compiler is not impacted. Also, if you assign 0.6694716 first to an extended variable, and then assign that variable to a double variable, you will also get 3fe56c4fb47339b4

Comment: I think this can only happen if the closest `Extended` to the value is exactly half way between the two double values, but that could be exactly what is happening here. The defect in that case is one of design, namely that we cannot attach a type to a float literal as we can in other languages.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan According to Delphi, 0.6694716 extended representation is exactly halfway between $3FE...B3 and $3FE...B4 extended representation.